# Javascript. Checking the type of response from a URL without downloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web application that can run reports on a server. The reports are stored on the server for a certain amount of time. When I send the report URL, the server either sends the report back (in XLS format) or it returns a simple "file not found" text (no error)
Next time the user logs in, I want to be able to check if the report is still there or it needs to be run again. I could simply use JQuery.ajax to call the URL in the background and check the type of response I get. However, this means that the reports are downloaded fully and I have 10s if not 100s of potential reports.
Is there any way that I can query the server so that I only get the type of response that I will get, without downloading the content (i.e. XLS, or binary-> the report is available; text -> the report is missing)?
Note that I have no control over the behavior of the server.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The request headers are a good place to check, as they likely contain the file type that will be sent. In order to retrieve the headers of a request only, without the body (which is what causes the download), just do

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("HEAD", url, async);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    request.getAllResponseHeaders()
  }
}
```

This `request.getAllResponseHeaders()` will contain headers that will have a `Content-Type`, if the api was built properly. That should give you an idea of whether there's a file available or not.

Comment: Good catch, updated the answer! xhr is an XMLHttpRequest, essentially an AJAX call without using jQuery

Comment: That should be proper implementation now

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var url = 'some_url';

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               var content_type = xhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
               if (content_type.indexOf('text/html') == -1){
                  alert('excel');
              }
              else {
                  alert('file not found');
              }
            }
            else {
                alert('invalid url');
            }
      };
      xhttp.open("HEAD", url, true);
      xhttp.send();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop, thanks for your comments that led me to this solution. Using JQuery this is what I have come up with, which seems to work:

```
req=$.ajax({
    type:'HEAD',
    url:'url',
success: function() {
            if(req.getAllResponseHeaders().indexOf("ms-excel.sheet")>=0{}//report is available            
            else{} //report is not available             
        }
});
```