# Check content of window.open() before opening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I have an API that either returns an Excel file for download or an error message as a string. I'm trying to download the Excel file or print the error message without redirecting to another page.

I'm trying to do:

```
let new_window = window.open("https://API/receivedoc?timestamp="+timestamp,"_self")
```

How can I check whether the request returned an Excel file and then download it (this does work currently) or a string? If it's a string, I'd like to pass it to a local variable and print it on the webpage in the `output` div like:

```
filerootdiv.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = /**parse returned text here**/;
```

I have no idea how to do this, as `window.open()` automatically redirects to the new page and if the API returns the string, it just shows a white page with the string.

**EDIT**

What works with JSON is this:

```
xhr1.open("GET", "https://API/predict?timestamp="+timestamp)
try {                
   self.data = JSON.parse(xhr1.response);
   filerootdiv.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = 'Complete!';
} catch(e){
   console.log("not JSON");
   filerootdiv.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = xhr1.response;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same error functionality except that instead of a JSON there's an Excel file returned by the API that needs to be downloaded for the user and NOT displayed on the site.

Or is there a way I can make an `xhr` request, make the error handling kinda the same as with the JSON above and *then* download a file? Is that possible? How?

Comment: If another origin, forget it

Comment: This might help if it's on the same domain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967509/javascript-checking-the-type-of-response-from-a-url-without-downloading-content

Answer (score -1):

You can check with [jquery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function before you download it.

```
$.get( "https://API/receivedoc?timestamp="+timestamp, function( data ) {
  if (data != ""){
     // Download file
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is right, as data would never be empty, it's either an Excel sheet or a non-empty string. Also, how do you download an Excel file contained in a variable? I couldn't figure it out. I also updated the question.

Comment: Also I'm using node, not jquery.